# Linux terminal that supports RTL (non KDE)

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, ubuntu, terminal-emulator

I am on Ubuntu unity 16.04, I am looking for:

- Free Linux terminal that supports RTL
- Not KDE based
- Works in ZSH because [bicoin does not](https://github.com/behdad/bicon)
- Huge bonus if it can be integrated in VScode, in fact the reason I want the terminal in the first place is because I am working on an RTL related project in VScode. As far as I know, konsole cannot do that
- I will accept your answer if you offer a VScode plugin that fixes the RTL issue in the VScode terminal, rather than a standalone terminal

The problem is not just RTL, the characters are showing but messed up, I'm working with Arabic, I have utf-8 enabled in, it is a terminal emulator program, all works well in Konsole but I don't want it since it's KDE and also doesn't integrate with VScode.

Answer (score 1):

My friend told me today about `mlterm`, available in all Linux distros repos. As for VS code, one can't change the default one. You can set it as an external terminal and open it with `ctrl + shift + c`